# Load image in angular-cli app with rel="preload"

Tags: html, angular, angular-cli

I have an angular-cli app that I would like to preload images for. I put the following tags in my index.html `<head>`:

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="assets/img/cards/10_of_clubs.png">
...
```

Those links are not 404s. That is, the asset pointed to loads in the browser: `<myhost>/assets/img/cards/10_of_clubs.png`.

But the preload doesn't work because the URLs generated in the stylesheet:

```
.r-10.s-3 {
  background-image: url(../../assets/img/cards/10_of_clubs.png);
}
```

Result in different URLS, a la: `/10_of_clubs.c7b975e5edc1b3444d45.png`

What I'd like to do is somehow reference the images in the assets directory in my index.html, and have angular-cli refer to them with their 'compiled' URLs.

BTW, I've also tried:

```
img = new Image();
img.src = '../assets/img/cards/10_of_clubs';
```

In my Typescript, but this seems to again reference the same path that I'm getting in my index.html attempt.

Comment: For this, you can use javascript tag like <img 
                      src="https://s13.postimg.org/ih41k9tqr/img1.jpg" onerror="this.src='../assets/img/cards/10_of_clubs;this.onerror='';" alt="User Image">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `--output-hashing=bundles`, will produce images without hash.

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing=bundles
```

> **Note:** HASH in image filename helps in [managing browser cache](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) after every build.

Answer (score -2):

You can use these code for show an image.

```
@Component({
   selector:'loading-image',
   template:'<img [src]="srcImg"/>'
})
srcImg:string = "../assets/img/cards/img.jpg"
```